# How to stop execution of code after return the value in a recursive function?

Tags: php, recursion, yii

I have a code like below in yii.

```
<?php
class MediaController extends Controller {
     public $mail_try = 1;

    public function actionUpdate() 
    {
        // ........... Other Code
        $return_err = array();
        /* Now Send Email */
        if(sizeof($mail_queue)>0)
        {
            foreach($mail_queue as $resmail)
            {
                $this->mail_try = 1;
                $to_arr = $resmail['to_arr'];
                $cc_arr = $resmail['cc_arr'];
                $from = $resmail['from'];
                $subject = $resmail['subject'];
                $message = $resmail['message'];
                $log_msg = $resmail['log_msg'];
                $attachment = $resmail['attachment'];
                $log =  $resmail['log'];
                $output = $this->mailsend($to_arr, $cc_arr, $from, $subject, $message, 'Image/Media update (action : insert) ', $attachment,$log);
                if($output==0)
                {
                    $return_err[] = $resmail['vendor_name'];
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public function mailsend($to, $cc, $from, $subject, $message, $crontask, $attachment = array(),$log='') {
        //.......  Other Code
        //.......  Other Code
        try{
             if (!$mail->Send()) {
                if($this->mail_try < 3)
                {
                    $this->mail_try++;
                    $this->mailsend($to, $cc, $from, $subject, $message, $crontask,$attachment,$log);
                    return 0;
                }
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

What i am trying to do is if mail sending is failed, then call the same function to retry to send the email. If email sending is still failed then return 0 else 1. Then using this return value i am trying to notify the user about mail sending error.

Earlier, i thought that code below the return value will not execute. But i am wrong. In above case it execute after the return value, because it is in recursive function.

So, How to solve this problem?

Comment: To be honest, I can't work out what you're saying your problem is. Quick look at the code though makes me thing that the `$this->mailsend(...)` line should be `return $this->mailsend(...)`, removing the following `return 0;`. Finally, there's a path by the looks of it which will return null when the mail fails twice.

Comment: The problem here is,  the code is executing even after the return value, so i can't get the expected return value. what i am tryig to do is return the 1 or 0 value after few try of sending the email.

Comment: So if i edit my code as suggest by you, it still executes code after the return value.

Comment: It doesn't continue running after return. `return` completes the process for the current block, in your case, the the calling block that gets returned to happens to be the same method which will finish running, that's what recursion does. But if the line simply returns when recursively calling `mailsend` then it should cascade returns down to the original call, and return back to your `actionUpdate` method with a 1 or 0 (if you fix the path that returns null).

Comment: Can you please write it as an answer with example code, sorry, but i am not able to got your point and what do you mean by "(if you fix the path that returns null)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 2 problems that I see with the code provided.

1) No matter whether the resend passes or fails, the method returns 0

2) If the function fails twice, the method will return null instead of 0 or 1 as there is no fallback to pick it up (i.e. when `$this->mail_try` is 3).

The following updated code is modified so that no matter what the return value is from a recursive call, it is returned back directly rather than returning just 0. The other change is that if it fails both times, it will return 0 instead of null

```
public function mailsend($to, $cc, $from, $subject, $message, $crontask, $attachment = array(),$log='') {
    //.......  Other Code
    //.......  Other Code
    try{
         if (!$mail->Send()) {
            if($this->mail_try < 3)
            {
                $this->mail_try++;
                return $this->mailsend($to, $cc, $from, $subject, $message, $crontask,$attachment,$log);
            }
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output if mailsend is failing at first, then in second trial it passes, then what is the return value? And the code after the return value is executed or it stop?

Comment: The current method ends as soon as it hits a `return` statement and returns to the original caller (which could be a previous run of `mailsend`). If the first `mailsend()` fails and the second succeeds, it should return `1`.

Comment: Another thing to note is that if an exception occurs, it won't try again beyond what has already happened, so if an exception is thrown on the original call of `mailsend` it won't try again. Not sure if that was intentional or not, that's a decision for you.

Comment: ok.. Thanks for your detailed explanation. But in this example "If the first mailsend() fails and the second succeeds" , the original caller for second is first mailsend(). So the execution of first mailsend() stop?
Sorry to be pain, but i am trying to clear my mind.

Comment: Yes, that's right. `actionUpdate` has the first call. If that fails, the `mailsend` method increments the counter and runs for a second time. There is no third time because of your `mail_try` default and condition.

Answer (score 0):

what is `mail->Send()` method?
if its for send the email, this is maybe can be an answer.

```
public function mailsend($to, $cc, $from, $subject, $message, $crontask, $attachment = array(),$log='') {
//.......  Other Code
//.......  Other Code
try{
     $this->mail_try = 1;
     while(!mail->Send() && $this->mail_try<=3){
        $this->mail_try++;
     }
     if($this->mail_try == 4){return 0;}//failed
     else {return 1;} //it means mail has been send before $this->mail_try = 3
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

its not tested yet, please try